# Sum of maximal element from every possible subset of size 'k' of an array

Tags: python, algorithm, subset

I have a very large list comprising of about 10,000 elements and each element is an integer as big as 5 billion. I would like to find the sum of maximal elements from every possible subset of size 'k' (given by the user) of an array whose maximum size is 10,000 elements. The only solution that comes to my head is to generate each of the subset (using itertools) and find its maximum element. But this would take an insane amount of time! What would be a pythonic way to solve this?

Comment: `combinations` is a generator, I would assume the program doesn't "hang" here. Can you show more code?

Comment: What's your `k`?  `binomial(10000, 4) == 416416712497500`.  Unless `k <= 3` or `k >= 9997`, then in practice you're never going to make it through all the combinations of a 10,000 element list.

Comment: it generates `n! / k! / (n-k)!` items, where `n = len(very_big_list)` and `x!` is factorial e.g., [for `n=10000; k=10` it is 2743355077591282538231819720749000 items](http://ideone.com/uiCHWB). It would take millions of Universe life-times to process it one billion items per second

Comment: Maybe we need to know more about the code that makes use of this result. This code runs immediately: `x = itertools.combinations(range(0, 10000), 4); x.next(); x.next(); x.next();`

Comment: @LevLevitsky I just tested the below code `a=list(itertools.combinations(range(5000),3))` and that caused my system to die again. I very much believe that's the reason.

Comment: @DSM `k` value varies and is provided by the user. You have raised an important point, but this problem is from a programming contest so I believe there should be some workaround for it.

Comment: @coding_pleasures: like others have stated, your bottleneck is most likely somewhere else

Comment: `list(itertools.combinations(range(5000),3))` would have 20820835000 elements.  You don't have nearly enough memory to store that, even if you were that patient.  Whatever problem you're trying to solve, if it's a contest problem, then there's a smarter way to solve it than manually looping through, much less instantiating in memory, enormous lists.

Comment: @minopret Actually this is the way I am using it my code: `a=list(itertools.combinations(range(5000),3))`. Thanks for your insight, maybe I could try in that direction.

Comment: @DSM You are right. Maybe you could pass some insight on my actual problem then: I need to find the sum of maximal elements from every possible subset of size 'k' generated from an array whose size could be a maximum of 10,000 elements.

Comment: @coding_pleasures: edit that into your question.  You've just fallen victim to the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where instead of asking about your real problem, you ask about your attempted solution.

Comment: But anyway: You can write a for-loop that runs over the (huge number of) results generated by `itertools.combinations()`. Just don't try to collect them all into a list-- that's why iterators are so useful.

Comment: @alexis Yeah, I was thinking along the same lines.

Comment: In your case, though, looping over 20820835000 subsets is almost certainly not the way to solve the problem. So rethink your approach or ask a new question. (@DSM, isn't it poor practice to completely change a question in the way you suggest?)

Comment: @alexis: I usually don't object when there are no answers to invalidate.  If the OP wants to delete this question and start again, that'd work too.

Comment: @DSM I have edited the question as you suggested. Please take another look at it.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use python, use mathematics first. This is a combinatorial problem: If you have an array `S` of *n* numbers (*n* large), and generate all possible subsets of size *k*, you want to calculate the sum of the maximal elements of the subsets.

Assuming the numbers are all distinct (though it also works if they are not), you can calculate exactly how often each will appear in a subset, and go on from there without ever actually constructing a subset. You should have taken it over to `math.stackexchange.com`, they'd have sorted you out in a jiffy. Here it is, but without the nice math notation:

Sort your array in increasing order and let `S_1` be the smallest (first) number,
`S_2` the next smallest, and so on. (Note: Indexing from 1).

1. `S_n`, the largest element, is obviously the maximal element of any subset
   it is part of, and there are exactly `(n-1 choose k-1)` such subsets.
2. Of the subsets that don't contain S_n, there are `(n-2 choose k-1)`
   subsets that contain `S_{n-1}`, in which it is the largest element.
3. Continue this until you come down to `S_k`, the `k-th` smallest number
   (counting from the smallest), which will be the maximum of exactly one
   subset: `(k-1 choose k-1) = 1`. Smaller numbers (`S_1` to `S_{k-1}`)
   can never be maximal: Every set of `k` elements will contain something
   larger.
4. Sum the above `(n-k+1 terms)`, and there's your answer:

   ```
   S_n*(n-1 choose k-1) + S_{n-1}*(n-2 choose k-1) + ... + S_k*(k-1 choose k-1)
   ```

   Writing the terms from smallest to largest, this is just the sum

   ```
   Sum(i=k..n) S_i * (i-1 choose k-1)
   ```

If we were on math.stackexchange you'd get it in the proper mathematical notation, but you get the idea.

Comment: PS. How does one flag a question for migration? I've read complaints about the current system on meta, but don't see how to do it if the site doesn't show up in the short list of options...

Comment: The only way is to flag for moderator attention. But I think this question belongs here rather than math.se since it's an algorithms question, and the math involved is rather basic.

Comment: I think there must be a closed-form sum, but I can't even write n-choose-k on this site. But let's see.

Comment: @alexis The numbers are distinct. Unfortunately I didn't 'get' your solution. Could you explain how to calculate exactly how often each number will appear in a subset?

Comment: "Smaller numbers are never maximal." doesn't seem right. Consider `k=1` then the answer is just sum of *all* numbers but your answer considers only a single maximum element.

Comment: `k=1` is the degenerate case, there _are_ no numbers less than k! The formula reduces to the sum of all the numbers, as it should, since `(n choose 0) = 1`. (Note that the `k-1` part never changes). So: `S_1 * (n-1 choose 0) + S_2 * (n-2 choose 0) + ...`

Comment: "Smaller numbers are never maximal" because if `k=3`, the two smallest numbers in your list will _never_ be the maximal element of any 3-element subset.

Comment: @alexis , This algorithm gave me the OMG moment of the day. very neat solution.

Comment: "counting upwards from the smallest" clarified your answer. I've confused "k-th smallest" with S_k initially. [here's implementation in Python](http://ideone.com/icZLWv)

Comment: @J.F. The fast binomial is a nice touch, but you could speed it up immensely by calculating the binomials from small to large and memoizing. (Also the formula would look simpler if I'd indexed from small to large; but I like this order for the exposition).

Comment: PS. I don't mean full memoizing: It's enough to remember the last binomial calculated...